# Relations in simplest form

Tags: functions, notation, relations

I'm struggling to comprehend what this question is asking me.

> Let $x$ and $y$ be integers where  $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
>       5 & x<y \\
>       f(x-y,y+2)+1 & x\ge y\\
>    \end{cases}$$
>   Express the following relation in it's simplest form:
>   $$f (2,7)$$

So far, I'm guessing this means rewrite into the correct notation. Am I on the right lines when I respond with:

$f$ : $X \leftrightarrow Y$

$x$ E $X$

$y$ E $Y$

$(x,y)$ E F

Comment: If you mean what you say $f(2,7)$ is the integer $5$. I cannot understand what the relation $5$ is.

Comment: What do the four last lines mean?